# Moving rows in 'Complete' status to another sheet in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to add a script to my sheet that would help to keep in cleaner by moving all completed rows from 'Main' sheet/tab to 'Completed' if the row is in the 'Complete' status. Filtering unfortunately isn't enough.

I was hoping it's something I can figure out on my own but have been running into errors when running the script I modified. Not sure if it's the right one. Could anyone point me towards a correct script?

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

**Here is the example sheet:**
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dGm-XddcndmvwcP-K61OViLpNTcMmKpI2rEQOYpVuJQ/edit?usp=sharing

## Here is the script I found and tried to modify to my own sheet but still got errors when renamed sheets and edited ranges:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('doneCopy', 'doneCopy')
      .addToUi();
}

function doneCopy() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Current");
  var values = sheet.getRange(1, 8, sheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
  var moveRows = values.reduce(function(ar, e, i) {
    if (e[0] == "DONE") ar.push(i + 1);
    return ar;
  }, []);
  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("OLD");
  moveRows.forEach(function(e) {
    sheet.getRange(e, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).moveTo(targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1));
  });
  moveRows.reverse().forEach(function(e) {sheet.deleteRow(e)});
}
```

Comment: When I saw your sample Spreadsheet, there is no sheet of "Current". And also, there are no values of "DONE" and "Completed" in column "A" in all 3 sheets. So, I'm worried that you might have miscopied your script or your sample Spreadsheet might be not correct. How about this? In this case, I cannot think of your current issue and your goal. I apologize that I am trying to correctly understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

There are three syntax errors in your code:

- the name of the source sheet

  - `var source = ss.getSheetByName("Main")`
- the name of the target sheet

  - `var target = ss.getSheetByName("Completed")`
- the value to match

  - `e[0] == "Complete"`

---

```
function doneCopy() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Main");
  var values = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();

  var moveRows = values.reduce(function(ar, e, i) {
    if (e[0] == "Complete") ar.push(i + 1);
    return ar;
  }, []);

  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Completed");
  moveRows.forEach(function(e) {
    sheet.getRange(e, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).moveTo(targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1));
  });
  moveRows.reverse().forEach(function(e) {sheet.deleteRow(e)});

}
```

Comment: Worked well, you rock!